# Audio.js | How to make it show only Play/Pause button

Tags: html, html5-audio, audiojs

So I have installed audio.js on my website. All works ok. I want it to change how it looks. Actually, I want that it would appear only as Play button (or play/pause button). Or in other words: I want to hide progress bar and "time passed | time remaining". How can I do this?

Comment: I have tried to edit audio.min.js, set the all width to 25px and it worked, alsmost... but the thing is that after button, in the same line must follow the text, but somewhy it is being put in another line. After button code in html there is no <br>, but somewhy the text is being shown in other line, so this is what I am trying to figure out now

Comment: So I have found that with audio.js it is by the default (or isn't it?) that further text will appear on new line... Any idea how can put it on the same line?

Comment: Can you please post your code or whatever the output you are getting.

Comment: It looks like this `<audio><source src="https://www.website.com/audio/test.mp3"></audio> This text is for testing purposes `and the result is that audio "Play" button is in one line and the text is in another line. This is not related with responsive design - the webpage can be in full screen, but result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

audiojs has `settings` that u can customize the style and markup, please refer to [the documentation](https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/)

If you wanna use default class names, you can overwrite their styles by adding css something like this:

```
.audiojs .scrubber { 
display: none; 
}
```

There is the working source code link: https://jsfiddle.net/qp5xjxb9/3/

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I prefer to choose width of most objects as 0 px in audio.min.js file. It worked better for me. But thanks for a guide!

Comment: Yes it was just direction for you. You can modify and change it depending on your purpose. You need to accept the answer for further developers who will try to find answers